# Семантика работы/хранения статики в CLR

Tags: c#, clr, static

Известно, что статика ***не*** привязана к ***объекту*** (экземпляру), а хранится в ***типе объекта*** (!), и соответственна эта статика (в виде полей/методов и т.д.), будет существовать в едином экземпляре для всех созданных объектов типа.

Другими словами, все созданные объекты !статического класса будут ссылаться на единственную версию этих статических методов/полей.

На фоне этого, возникает вопрос, а как лучше всего ***использовать статику***, ведь объекты с модификатором `static`  не подлежат сборке мусора, т.к. хранятся в типе объекта (который в свою очередь связан с доменом приложения, и будет существовать до конца жизненного цикла приложения).

Стоит ли избегать статические коллекции/массивы, которые работают с большим кол-вом данных (или же стоит, но нужно будет их "чистить вручную")?

Что является дурным тонном по использованию статики?

Или же можно использовать статику в таком же количестве, как и экземплярные варианты?

Comment: немного неверная формулировка, объект(экземпляр) не может иметь модификатор static. Этот модификатор может иметь поле, хранящее ссылку на объект. А значит этот объект также может быть удален GC, если мы удалим из статического поля ссылку на него. Так что проблемы с использованием статики в этом контексте нет. Но устроить утечку памяти забыв про ссылки на тяжелые объекты в статических полях можно элементарно.

Comment: @rdorn "немного неверная формулировка, объект(экземпляр) не может иметь модификатор static." - что то ты тут опять путаешь.

Статика не подлежит удалению от GC,перечитай мой пост внимательнее.

Comment: к тому же статика практически безобидна, по сравнению с делегатами и лямдами, в плане утечек, не говоря уже про неуправляемые ресурсы, и подключаемые нативные библиотеки, которые сами по себе иногда подтекают.

Comment: не подлежат удалению поля и методы, это да. Объект типа будет висеть в памяти с первого обращения до выгрузки домена. Но поле типа массив, не содержит сам массив, а только ссылку на него

Comment: Конечно есть один злобный вариант, объявить статическое поле с огромной структурой внутри, но это уже целенаправленная диверсия =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Я думаю, что стоит руководствоваться не «физическими» особенностями хранения, а семантикой, смыслом ваших данных.

Если у вас какой-либо метод или данные относится ко *всем* экземплярам класса, то этот метод/данные следует объявлять статическими. Если же у вас, например, экземпляр существует в единственном числе в системе, то следует объявлять его синглтоном.

Это должно быть главным соображением, влияющим на то, как именно вы объявляете ваши данные. Если в вашей программе *по её смыслу* данные являются статическими, объявляйте их статическими. Если они по своей сути являются экземпляром, объявляйте их данными экземпляра.

Пример: цвет автомашины, выпускаемой концерном Генри Форда — [чёрный](http://www.epwr.ru/quotation/txt_414.php). Значит, это статические данные:

```
class FordCar
{
    public static readonly Color = Colors.Black;
}
```

В моей компании есть на текущий момент только одна машина. Но это всё равно конкретный экземпляр. Значит, это [синглтон](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx):

```
class OurCompanyCar
{
    private OurCompanyCar() { }
    public static OurCompanyCar() Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    private static readonly Lazy<OurCompanyCar> lazy =
        new Lazy<OurCompanyCar>(() => new OurCompanyCar());
}
```

Comment: Благодарю,солидарен. Но все же смею возразить,а именно тот момент,что "смысл данных" ,как минимум,должен опираться(базироваться) на том,как это все дело будет храниться в памяти,во избежания утечек и тд. В общем статика не панацея,и использовать её нужно с умом и в малых дозах.

Comment: @CSharpUser не должен.

Comment: @CSharpUser если данные *требуются* постоянно - то их *придется* хранить постоянно, независимо от того как вы организуете хранение.

Comment: @PavelMayorov а как же кеширование?(с дальнейшим сохранением в память,и обратным процессом). Не всегда есть смысл держать все в памяти. :)

Comment: @CSharpUser а кешированные данные и не имеют семантики постоянных.